# How to send and receive HMAC(Hashed Message Authentication Code) CAN messages in SocketCAN?

Tags: python, shell, cryptography, hmac, socketcan

HMAC CODE

```
import hmac, hashlib

def _generate_signature(data):
  key = '123' # Defined as a simple string.
  key_bytes= bytes(key , 'latin-1')
  data_bytes = bytes(data, 'latin-1') # Assumes `data` is also a string.
  return hmac.new(key_bytes, data_bytes , hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

print(
  _generate_signature('i am priyam')
)
```

TO SEND AND RECEIVE MESSAGE IN SOCKET CAN

```
ifconfig vcan0
sudo modprobe vcan
sudo ip link add dev vcan0 type vcan
sudo ip link set up vcan0
cansend vcan0 123#1122334455667788
candump vcan0
```

Comment: Please always include the language / runtime environment in the tags (this is Python & shell scripting, I presume?). Also describe any error message you are getting. You've shown that you've tried stuff, but how is it failing?

Comment: I have simulated HMAC separately in python shell and message passing has been implemented in SocketCAN. I want to know how to send HMAC message in SocketCAN